# KStreams turn off the internal topics for Aggregate

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am working on an application where the Kafka by default has 'auto topic' creation disabled. So any topics required by the application should be be created prior.
I have implemented a Window store with aggregation..

```
    KGroupedStream<String, String> groupedStream = builder.stream("topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
            .map(this::processInbound)
            .groupByKey();


    WindowBytesStoreSupplier windowStoreSupplier  = Stores.persistentWindowStore(storename, STORE_RETENTION, WINDOW_SIZE, false);
    final Materialized<String, StatAggregator, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> materialized  = Materialized.
            <String, StatAggregator>as(windowStoreSupplier )
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withValueSerde(Serdes.String());

    groupedStream.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(1day).advanceBy(15mins))
            .aggregate(StatAggregator::new, (key, value, aggregator) -> {
                aggregator.add(value);
                return aggregator;
            }, materialized );
```

I need the fault tolerance to be in place, so I create the change log and the partition topics prior..ie the topics xxxxx-store-changelog and xxxxx-store-repartition are already created before app launch.
But as I use aggregation I see that the there are other internal topics created by KStreams like xxxxx-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000031-changelog and xxxxx-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000031-repartition etc... As these topics names are derived by the KStreams itself I am unable to create them prior.
I would like to either turn off the auto topic creation for AGGREGATE or able to define the name of the topics prior (config?) so that the KStreams can use them for aggregation.
Please advise.

Thanks,
Jinu